# French whisk handle has rocks in it?

Tags: utensils

I'm at a restaurant supply store and I'm looking to buy this heavy duty French whisk manufactured by the company WINCO and I'm shaking the handle and it sounds like there are small rocks or sand in them.

They all have it.

What's that about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be sand, used to weight the handle. The weight is an important part of the design. I assume some manufacturers use sand instead of just thicker/heavier steel because it's cheaper and easier to manufacture.

For proof that at least some whisks are made like this, here's [a whisk with Amazon reviews that mention sand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005EBH9) and even a picture:

[image]

It's just inert weight. It's not going to come into contact with your food. I guess if you get a defective one and the handle comes open and dumps sand in your food, you'd have to throw it out, but otherwise it's not really anything to worry about.

Comment: But is it dangerous?

Comment: @DannyRodriguez I wouldn't think so, edited.

Comment: Can you direct me in the way any French whisks that don't have non-stainless steel material in them. I wanted to buy this whisk cause it's cheap($4.50) and cause the wires on it are really thick which would be perfect for bechamel and other thick sauces. Inert weight or not, it still makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez We don't really do shopping recommendations here... like I said, this doesn't seem like an issue, but if it bothers you, there are a ton of whisks out there and I'm sure they're not *all* made this way. You might be overrestricting by looking for *French* whisks; this is really just a stainless steel balloon whisk, and since balloon whisks are the most common kind, I imagine it'd get called a stainless steel whisk most of the time.

Comment: You do want a properly weighted whisk. Believe it or not you are more likely to grip an unweighted whisk harder. The weight actually makes you relax more and therefore aren't killing you forearms as much when whisking.

Comment: @DannyRodriguez As for making you uncomfortable, consider that most of your food (e.g. carrots) is a much more likely vector for you ingesting sand than your (encapsulated) whisk handle. Ingesting sand happens all the time and the human body deals with it easily. So, no reason to be afraid of your food getting contaminated.